# NameError: name 'process' is not defined (python)

Tags: python, nameerror

I have a python script which looks like:

```
 if options.benchmark == 'perlbench':
     process = Mybench.perlbench
 elif options.benchmark == 'bzip2':
     process = Mybench.bzip2
 elif options.benchmark == 'gcc':
     process = Mybench.gcc
 ....
 np = 1
 ....
 for i in xrange(np):   
     ... 
     system.cpu[i].workload = process[i]
```

However I get this error:

```
system.cpu[i].workload = process[i]

NameError: name 'process' is not defined
```

Any idea on how to fix that? I am not an expert in python.

Comment: What was the value of `options.benchmark` when you got this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snippet you've posted appears to be from the `cmp.py` script posted [here](http://gem5.org/SPEC_CPU2006_benchmarks) (link currently down).

This script is being run on the command line and requires a valid value to be specified for `-b` or `--benchmark`. You are either not specifying one or are specifying an invalid one.

The script may be modified by adding an `else` case to display a more useful error, but it still won't work unless you use an appropriate value.

For example, you could try this:

```
python cmp.py --benchmark perlbench
```

Answer (score 3):

That means that your block

```
if options.benchmark == 'perlbench':
     process = Mybench.perlbench
elif options.benchmark == 'bzip2':
     process = Mybench.bzip2
elif options.benchmark == 'gcc':
     process = Mybench.gcc
```

didn't match any of `options.benchmark` so the variable `process` was never assigned anything.  You need to throw an

```
else:
    process = Mybench.<somedefault>
```

on the end of it (of course filling in `<somedefault>` as appropriate).  Or if that's an invalid case, you could raise an exception, perhaps.